# Combine two Stream into one Flux

Tags: java, java-stream, project-reactor

How can I combine two streams `Stream<String>` into `Flux`? What I understand is that I might need to use Flux create method to create this but I am not really sure about it:

```
flux1.create(sink -> {
    sink.onRequest(L -> {
        for(long l = 0; l < L; l++) {
            sink.next(..);
        }
    });
})
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concat the `Stream`s into one and then invoke `Flux#fromStream`:

```
Flux<String> flux = Flux.fromStream(Stream.concat(stream1, stream2));
```

Another way of doing this would be to create a `Flux` using `Flux#fromStream` and then `Flux#merge`:

```
Flux<String> flux = Flux.merge(flux1, flux2);
```