# How to get a Flux<MyPojo> from multiple Flux<MyPojo>?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

How to get a `Flux<MyPojo>` from multiple `Flux<MyPojo>`?

In a very simple case:

```java
public Flux<MyPojo> question() {
    Flux<MyPojo> flux1 = getFluxMyPojoViaAPI();
    Flux<MyPojo> flux2 = repository.findAll();
    Flux<MyPojo> flux3 = getFluxMyPojoViaAnotherAPI();
    Flux<MyPojo> flux4 = etc();

    Flux<MyPojo> everythingTogetherAsFluxMyPojo = //how to achieve this please?
    return everythingTogetherAsFluxMyPojo;
```

I was wondering how to get the `Flux<MyPojo>` from all the previously computed `Flux<MyPojo>`

Tried zip, and those related APIs, and ended up with a Flux of Tuples.

Is there a simpler and better way to achieve getting a `Flux<MyPojo>` from multiples `Flux<MyPojo>` please?

Comment: there are several ways, a simple google search https://www.baeldung.com/reactor-combine-streams

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two Stream into one Flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971297/combine-two-stream-into-one-flux)

Comment: Actually yes. If you want, just put it as answer, I can accept it

Comment: no i wont because its a duplicate, and this question should be closed

Comment: Then, let's close it

Comment: Related: [Spring Reactor Merge vs Concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478420/spring-reactor-merge-vs-concat)

Comment: @Toerktumlare It is not really a duplicate though, the other question asks how to combine two streams into a single flux.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so you felt the need to answer the question after i helped him. Okey.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Yes, because the question you directed him to is not a duplicate of this question (the fact that the answer helped him solve it, is IMHO not sufficient reason to consider those questions duplicate), and as I couldn't actually find a suitable duplicate (the one I posted as _related_ in the comment above came closest), I decided to post an answer.

Comment: Sure, or one could have told me to write an answer if one thought it wasn't a duplicate. But, fine, to each our own. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Flux.merge(Publisher<? extends I>... sources)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#merge-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-):

```java
Flux<MyPojo> combined = Flux.merge(flux1, flux2, flux3, flux4)
```

or [`Flux.concat(Publisher<? extends T>... sources)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concat-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-):

```java
Flux<MyPojo> combined = Flux.concat(flux1, flux2, flux3, flux4)
```

The important difference between `merge` and `concat` is that `merge` will subscribe all fluxes together, and publish items as they arrive on any flux, while `concat` will first subscribe the first flux and publish its items until it completes, then subscribe the next flux, etc.

Comment: While the post and web article helped me, the actual solution I ended up using was the one Mark proposed (that I derived from the web articles and the "duplicates". I am accepting this as solution

Comment: Upvoting this comment as well: "Does this answer your question? Combine two Stream into one Flux" since it is the one that actually helped me derive this accepted answer